# IE8 and 9 don't open new tabs

Tags: internet-explorer, browsing, tabbed-browsing

Internet Exporer 8 and 9 don't open a new tab when I middle-click, right click and select "Open in New Tab", or control-click. I’ve searched for a solution but I haven’t found a working solution. The problem also occurs when in "No Addons" mode.

Comment: Resetting Internet Explorer settings many times solved the problem in IE 64bits, problem still present in default IE and in No Addons mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Internet Explorer settings:

> To use the Reset Internet Explorer Settings feature from Control Panel, follow these steps:
>
> Exit all programs, including Internet Explorer (if it is running).
>
> If you use Windows Vista or 7, click the **Start
>   button**. Type the following command in
>   the Start Search box, and then press
>   ENTER: **inetcpl.cpl**
>
> The Internet
>   Options dialog box appears.
>
> Click the
>   **Advanced tab**. Under **Reset Internet Explorer settings**, click **Reset**. Then
>   click **Reset** again.
>
> When Internet
>   Explorer finishes resetting the
>   settings, click **Close** in the Reset
>   Internet Explorer Settings dialog box.
>
> Start Internet Explorer again.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that before with no luck, I tried twice as you said and the problem is still present BUT running IE (64 bits) it works, but default IE and IE-no-addons still have the problem. Any clue?